# Is it possible via HTML5/jQuery to get HTTP Headers from a video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, http-headers

We're playing around with jPlayer, and we want to be able to inspect the http headers (even from a remote user so wireshark is not possible) from the video file as it is getting parsed -- you can assume we're just going to use the video tag. You can get headers from an AJAX call in jQuery, so I was wondering if it's possible to get the headers from any resource, be it an image, video, css file, etc?

Comment: you can get the headers from a video url the same as a page url.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I made it clear, but I'm trying to get the headers programmatically, as opposed to using a tool.

Comment: i don't understand, is jQuery ajax not programmatic?

Comment: yes, but if I have `<video src = 'http://somesite.com/video.mp4'></video>`, the question is, how can jQuery get the response headers?

Answer (score 0):

within the browser you cannot today, it would need to be via an external tool.

I would suggest piling on this request - https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14310 - with your use-case